# Install openCV on xcode for c++

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I have problems to install openCV on xcode in order to develop in C++. 
I tried to follow this [tutorial](http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/)

But, I have a problem when I do the `make` command in the terminal, I have this kind of error:

> fatal error: 
>   
>       'QTKit/QTKit.h' file not found
>   
>        #import 
>   
>        1 error generated.
>   
>        make[2]: ***
>   
>       [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_qtkit.mm.o] Error 1

Do you have any solution?

Comment: did you checked your pathes? Maybe it comes from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install OpenCV through homebrew. To do this, open terminal and run the following commands.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" 
brew install homebrew/science/opencv3
```

Last command will install OpenCV3 and all dependencies in /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0.3/

Then you can link .dylib and .h/.hpp files to your XCode project and use OpenCV.

If you have any questions, I'm happy to answer them.

**[EDIT]:**
If you use macOS 10.12 or later, install OpenCV with following commands.

```
brew install opencv3 --with-ffmpeg --with-tbb --with-contrib
brew reinstall opencv3 --HEAD --with-python3 --with-ffmpeg --with-tbb --with-contrib
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried your command but i still have the same error :               
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
        ^
1 error generated.

Comment: @andresouris, which version of macOS do you use?

Comment: I'm using the version 10.12.1 on macOS sierra

Comment: @andresouris, oh, a few days ago my girlfriend faced your problem and solved it, I'll ask her to respond to you when I get home :)